# How create money balance for users in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model

I have users model and I want create for them balance with coins 
And Users can spend coins for posts model
Coins have to   **belongs_to :user**

And  posts alredy belongs_to :user
I want some users create post with price, and different users can buy it by coins. How do it ? Thanks

Comment: This question is really too general for StackOverflow. You should work through a beginner's Rails tutorial, try to work out your issue, and then come back with specific questions as necessary.

Comment: Simplest solution: drop the Coins model. Instead a User has a field `balance`, and a `Post` has a field `price`. Any time a user wants to read a `Post`, you deduct `price` from `balance`. As long as `balance` is > 0, the user is able to "buy" the Post and read it. For more specific solutions you have to ask more specific questions, as @moveson suggested.

Comment: @Casper It is a good idea, I create balance for users, but how to do like that: When user press to donate, will minus from his balance and plus to post.My project like Kickstarter. Users can choose how much they want to spend

Answer (score 0):

The question is very generic but this could give you an start.

For a single currency you could start with a ledger around these lines.

```
Table: coins (user_id, amount, balance, is_void, voided_id, , date_created, date_voided, ...)

First Scenario
1. +10, 10, false, nil, ...dates...
2. +20, 30, false, nil, ...dates...
3. +5,  35, false, nil, ...dates...
4. -1,  34, false, nil, ...dates...


Second Scenario (voided transaction)
1. +10, 10, false, nil, ...dates...
2. +20, 30, false, nil, ...dates...
3. +5,  35, true,  nil, ...dates...
4. -1,  34, false, nil, ...dates...
5. -5,  29, false, 3  , ...dates...
```

You need to be able to reconcile, so last balance should match the total of non voided/returned transactions (is_void == false and voided == nil)

```
ex. First scenario  10 + 20 + 5 - 1 = 34
    Second scenario 10 + 20 - 1 = 29
```

It is critical to make sure your transactions are ACID so you don't get into racing conditions. And ensuring it will be the most important part so the transaction history is accurate. And this is a very big topic.